# How can I synchronise Enketo captured data with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, data-synchronization

I have a ready made web application running on PHP and Mysql. We are considering switching to Enketo forms, embedded or otherwise for their offline capability and quick to launch capabilities.

I have scouted over google but cant find any direction on how to synchronise Enketo captured data to my MySQL database. There's the option to download the form as csv, convert, and import into my database but that presents obvious downsides.

I'm currently using enketo on KoboToolbox but can switch towards a self-hosted server or preferably another provider. I am not interested in keeping the data on KoBo or any other provider, but have no problems doing that. Can the Enketo API on apidocs.enketo.org help?

I would like and will appreciate any direction given towards this.

Github issue: https://github.com/enketo/enketo-core/issues/359

Answer (score 1):

This answer states that the API on KoBoToolbox can achieve this. http://support.kobotoolbox.org/customer/portal/questions/11665485-api

API https://kc.kobotoolbox.org/api/v1/